# Use get variable when rewritten url in wordpress

Tags: categories, terms

I have many pages which have a lot in common. They are supposed to display the same things but according to their own categories.
The logical way to implement this would be to pass a variable through the url and display the info according to it.

The only problem is that my wordpress urls are rewritten...

I search this site before asking and I know there are posts around here related to that matter but they don't help me as they refer to some obscure regex I just can't associate to my own case. Not to mention some unexplained references to "tags" and "rules" which are quite beyond me. I reallly tried to learn from theses posts but I couldn't make use of them.

Basically, my urls are rewritten and I need to add a single variable to this:
"http://www.mysite/(mycategory)

I don't know how to send the "mycategory" variable AND I don't know how to retrieve it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did is rewrite url's in order to display the categories on them.
After that, I just extracted them with the function "get_category_by_path".
It allowed me to use the url info without having to inject and extract any custom variable.
Thank you.

Comment: Please update your answer with the code that you used.

Answer (score 0):

If you want one template that looks the same for all of your categories, you do not need to do anything with regexes or $_GET variables. Just use an `archive.php` template within your theme, as detailed in the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates).

Comment: I tried what you asked but it didn't help me for what I needed. Maybe I didn't understand your answer right. If so, I'm sorry and thank you for your help